# How to do 2 different counts on the same query SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count

I have joined to 2 tables by

```
SELECT ccc.supplier_id as supplier_id, c1.name as supplier, ccc.dealer_id as dealer_id, c2.name as dealer
FROM company_companyconnection ccc 
left JOIN companies_company c1 ON c1.id = ccc.supplier_id
left JOIN companies_company c2 on c2.id = ccc.dealer_id
ORDER BY supplier_id ASC
```

so that I get results like:

| supplier_id | supplier | dealer_id | dealer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | company1 | 3 | company3 |
| 1 | company1 | 2 | company2 |
| 2 | company2 | 3 | company3 |

Now I want to do 2 different counts on the same query so that I can see counts going both ways, ie something like

| company_id | company | as_supplier_count | as_dealer_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | company1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | company2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | company3 | 0 | 2 |

I've managed to do so far

```
SELECT ccc.supplier_id as company_id, c1.name as company, count(ccc.dealer_id) as as_supplier_connections
FROM company_companyconnection ccc 
left JOIN companies_company c1 ON c1.id = ccc.supplier_id
JOIN companies_company c2 on c2.id = ccc.dealer_id
GROUP BY ccc.supplier_id, c1.name
ORDER BY supplier_id ASC
```

| company_id | company | as_supplier_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | company1 | 2 |
| 2 | company2 | 1 |
| 3 | company3 | 0 |

but I am having trouble with the final stage, any help would be amazing thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot and aggregate:

```
SELECT cc.*,
       count(*) filter (where v.which = 'supplier') as num_supplier,
       count(*) filter (where v.which = 'dealer') as num_dealer
FROM companies_company cc left join
     (company_companyconnection ccc cross join lateral
      (values (supplier_id, 'supplier'),
              (dealer_id, 'dealer')
      ) v(company_id, which)
     )
     on v.company_id = cc.id
group by cc.id;
```

Note:  The `group by cc.id` assumes that `companies_company(id)` is the primary key of the table (or at least declared as `unique`).  Otherwise, you need to list the columns in both the `select` and the `group by`.